# Rails assign_multiparameter_attributes for email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a rails 3.0 application.
My client wants me to split email information into username + @ + domainname in view.
I don't want to split the email field into two.
I just want to make virtual attributes like datetime_select.

Example:
user = User.new
attributes => {"email(1s)" => "sam", "email(2s)" => "domain.com"}

This pseudo-code doesn't work, of course.
What can I do about it?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 2):

It is the way to use same way with Rails helper methods.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_multiparameter_attributes

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing would be

```
 #user.rb
 before_save :update_email
 attr_accessor :email_name, :email_domain
 def update_email
   self.email = "#{self.email_name}@#{self.email_domain}"
 end
```